# Connection to Windows SMB share works through smbclient, fails to mount via mount.cifs

Tags: samba, centos6, windows-server-2019, cifs

I'm trying to access a Windows Server 2019 share (inside a domain) from a CentOS6 host.

I can browse the share via smbclient, but mounting fails:

`Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13 CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13`

On the Windows side, it complain about the following (from the Event Viewer):

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
                Security ID:                            NULL SID
                Account Name:                     -
                Account Domain:                  -
                Logon ID:                               0x0

Logon Type:                                          3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
                Security ID:                            NULL SID
                Account Name:                    [USER]
                Account Domain:                  [DOMAIN]

Failure Information:
                Failure Reason:                      Unknown user name or bad password.
                Status:                                    0xC000006D
                Sub Status:                            0xC000006A

Process Information:
                Caller Process ID:  0x0
                Caller Process Name:           -

Network Information:
                Workstation Name:              \\[IP]
                Source Network Address:    [IP]
                Source Port:                          46041

Detailed Authentication Information:
                Logon Process:                     NtLmSsp 
                Authentication Package:     NTLM
                Transited Services:                -
                Package Name (NTLM only):              -
                Key Length:                           0
```

However, the credentials are absolutely correct - I've also tried creating a brand new user as well, with the same error.

I'm not really sure how to diagnose this - help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue as you. I can connect via smbclient but mounting fails with the -13 error code. It is worth mentioning in my case I do not control the SMB server and cannot check any logs on the server end of things. Did you ever solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

What version of samba do you have installed?
Query via `rpm -qa | grep samba`
Make sure you have samba4 installed.

I am assuming the issue is related to version of SMB protocol the client is trying to use when connecting. SMB Version 1 is now disabled by default on Windows Server 2019. I would not recommend enabling it.

This is an example on adding debugging. Focus on the -d10 option. 
`smbclient  -U user //10.0.0.20/shares password -d10`
Note that to connect to a Windows 2012 server with encrypted transport selecting a max-protocol of SMB3 is required.
`smbclient -m SMB3 -U user //10.0.0.20/shares password -d10`

Find out what version of SMB your are running on the windows file server. SMBv1 is likely disabled by default

Run: `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` in powershell on the server.

 This will give you the smb server information.

Run `Get-SmbConnection` in powershell to see the current connections on the server
`PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbConnection`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SmbConnection

ServerName ShareName UserName      Credential    Dialect NumOpens
---------- --------- --------      ----------    ------- --------
localhost  IPC$      TEST\bit      TEST\bit      3.1.1   0
```

Check out for troubleshooting information https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3

Try  cifs client
Check out about versions of SMB https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/mounting_an_smb_share

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! 
I'll give your suggestions a shot and report back.